# Rename Nested Json data in schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Hey guys I am brand new to Spark/Scala and I wanted to rename a few nested JSON fields because when I am doing a lateral view it fails because there are multiple JSON fields with the same name.

I want to rename the columns EffDate and ExpDate in EmployeeAddr and EmployeePhone.

I've tried withColumnRenamed and withColumn functions but both aren't working for me for some reason.

```
Code to load into dataframe:
val Employee= spark.read.format(Employeefile_type).option("header", "true").option("inferSchema","true").load(file_loction)



root
 |-- BirthDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EmployeeId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EmployeeAddr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- AddrTypeName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- City: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- CtryCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- EffDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ExpDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- PostalCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Province: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Street1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Street2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EmployeeEmail: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- CrewEmailAddr: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- EmailType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EmployeeEmerContact: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Addr: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- FirstName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- LastName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- PrimaryPhone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Relatnshp: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EmployeeEmplymntStatus: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- EmplymntStatusCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- EmplymntStatusReason: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- EndDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- StartDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EmployeePhone: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- EmployeePhoneNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- EffDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ExpDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- PhoneType: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the solution described here:

[How to rename fields in an DataFrame corresponding to nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050658/how-to-rename-fields-in-an-dataframe-corresponding-to-nested-json/39993500)

It does the following, replace a DataFrame schema (re-creating DataFrame with a new schema.